# Does the use of GCC small macros and linker variables make my work GPL?

Tags: gpl-3, license, gcc

when using AVR or ARM toolchains for Atmel microcontrollers, is using GCC macros such as `__AVR_...__` or linker variables making my code GPL?

I know GCC is covered by "GPL 3.0" + "GCC Runtime Library Exception" but I am not sure if this exception covers the use of small macros like above.

And the linker is ld from binutils, which is covered by "GPL 3.0".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, GCC macros and linker variables are covered by the GCC Runtime Library Exception, see

> [...] in this way, the header files and runtime libraries covered by this Exception.

There are no clues that the built-in libraries should not be part of the exceptions.

Comment: the linker ld is from binutils. According to the FAQ of GCC Runtime Library Exception, "GCC Runtime Library Exception covers any file that has a notice in its license headers stating that the exception applies. This includes libgcc, libstdc++, libfortran, libgomp, libdecnumber, libgcov, and other libraries distributed with GCC". But it does not mention clearly binutils.